# Git Pre-Commit Using Sed To Dynamically Inject Branch Name

Tags: git, bash, sed, osx-elcapitan, pre-commit-hook

I am using a `git` pre-commit hook to:

1. Get the current branch name
2. Insert the branch name into a build status image code
3. Search the README.md file for a string/pattern and then use that string/pattern as a marker for where I want to insert the dynamically generated build status image.

Note that I am using OSX El Capitan v10.11.5 and in order to execute this code I had to run `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit` on the pre-commit script.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash

function git_branch {
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
}

branch=$(git_branch)
id="{{CODESHIP_CODE}}"

codeship_build_status="[ ![Codeship Status for ExampleUser/exampleRepo](https://codeship.com/projects/a99d9999-9b9f-9999-99aa-999k9b9b0999/status?branch=$branch)](https://codeship.com/projects/999999)"

sed -i -e "s%{{CODESHIP_CODE}}%$codeship_build_status%g" README.md
```

As of right now the code is kind of working. By that I mean it is:

1. Correctly searching the README.md file
2. Removing the string/pattern marker
3. Replacing the string/pattern marker with the `codeship_build_status` variable.

The issue is that this doesn't appear to be actually changing the README.md file prior to the `git commit` and instead it generates another file called README.md-e

When I go to `git push`and view the code in the repo the README.md file has not been updated and instead still contains the string/pattern marker instead of the updated build status image. Ironically enough the README.md file does get changed inside my local development branch.

Any ideas how to fix this issue or what may be causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `sed -i`. That tells `sed` to create a new file, and retain the old file with a new name, using the next parameter (in your case, `-e`) as the suffix.

For the Mac version of `sed`, you *must* provide a qualifying parameter for `-i`. To make it do the same thing the gnu / linux version would with those command line options, you want to provide a blank option, like this:

```
sed -i '' -e "s%{{CODESHIP_CODE}}%$codeship_build_status%g" README.md
```

Comment: ++; that's indeed the problem; quibble: `-i` doesn't create a _new_ file; rather, it _renames_ the _original_ file, if a nonempty option-argument is specified (otherwise it just _deletes_ the original file); it is `sed`'s output that creates a _new_ file, eventually renamed to the _original name_. (On a side note: it is this very approach of creating a temp. file and then renaming it to replace the original that can cause problems, most notably the destruction of a symlink.)

Comment: End result is that with `-i.bak`, you end up with two files: a file is created. With `-i ''`, you end up with one file.

Comment: No argument about the _end result_. My point was that it _may matter_ that the _original file_ is _renamed_ and its replacement is a _new_, temp. file that is then renamed to the original file _name_.
With this approach - which `sed` uses -  you'll  potentially lose the following properties of the _original_ file: most notably, _whether it was a symlink or not_, but also its _creation timestamp_ (on filesystems that support it (e.g., OSX)), _extended filesystem attributes_ (on filesystems that support it (e.g., OSX)). (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd from previous comment) By saying that `-i` "creates a new file" (rather than _renaming_ the original and replacing it with a _new_ file) you're glossing over these potentially important side effects; `sed` is not alone in this flawed approach, however: both `awk` and `perl` use it too.

Comment: Thank you all! This was driving me crazy, I really appreciate the fantastic help!

Comment: @Corey: Glad to hear it helped; one additional note: while you can typically formulate `sed` commands that work with _both_ GNU and BSD/OSX `sed` (by staying close to the POSIX spec.), the (nonstandard) `-i` option is an unfortunate exception: if you want to update "in-place" _without_ creating a backup file (read: keeping the original file by renaming it), there is no single syntax that works with both implementations.

Comment: Doesn't `-i.bak` followed by `rm file.bak` work in both?

Comment: @mklement0 thank you for that additional information thats good to know, such that if I ever run into such an issue I'll immediately know the reason and how to fix it... Thank you again for adding even more clarity to the situation, I appreciate it!

Comment: @PaulHicks: Yes, that's a viable workaround (involving an additional command, which is the unfortunate part).

Comment: @PaulHicks can you explain your solution in more detail?

Comment: @Corey: By specifying _any nonempty_ option-argument -- `.bak`, in this case  -- you make _both_ implementations happy (GNU Sed accepts the option-argument _only_ when _directly appended_ to `-i`; BSD/OSX Sed _also_ accepts that (in addition to allowing whitespace to separate `-i` from its option-argument)). The price of specifying a nonempty option-argument is invariably that the original file is retained (renamed to the original filename suffixed with the option-argument), so you then have to remove that unwanted "backup" file using a separate command.

Comment: @mklement0 so then using your example it would look like this ```sed -i.bak -e "s%{{CODESHIP_CODE}}%$codeship_build_status%g" README.md rm README.bak```?

Comment: @Corey: Correct (assuming that you meant to place the `rm` command on a separate line), though I suggest placing `&&` between the `sed` and `rm` commands on a _single_ line, so that `rm` is only attempted if the `sed` command succeeds.

Comment: @mklement0 you are correct, I was implying that it was on a separate line but I like your suggestion of using ```&&```